# heavy IO parallelization in python using concurrent.futures

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I was trying to parallel large file processing using **ProcessPoolExecutor** in **concurrent.futures**. The processing is relatively simple, but the I/O is heavy: reading thousands of 2G input file and writing 2G output files. Here is the pseudocode:

```
def process_single_file(file):
    output = process(file)
    write(output)

With concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    collections.deque(executor.map(process_single_file, file_list), maxlen=0)
```

I ran the code on a 48 core workstation and the performance is very poor. The program experienced frequent freezings. It actually ran quite well (much faster than unparalleled version) on my laptop with SSD and a few test files.

I have no experience with parallel programming and wonder what's the reason for the freezing and what's the best practice in this case using python.

Thank you!

Comment: How many read/write heads does your disk array have ?  How many channels are there from disk to RAM ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with hardware. The workstation is a "SuperMicro SYS-7048GR-TR 4U Server with X10DRG-Q Motherboard" mounted with a 6TB drive. The memory is 256 GB in total, but only a small fraction (< 10%) was used when the program is running. Right now only a single hard drive is mounted on the workstation, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: With one hard drive it is extremely likely that you have only one channel from disk to RAM.  If many processes try to read different files at the same time there will be tremendous contention for the single channel.  The result will be a slowdown in overall read rate, possibly a very considerable slow down if you really are trying to read thousands of files 'simultaneously'.  A better strategy is to have one process read enough files to fill RAM, process them in parallel, write the results (again, one process does that), repeat until done.

Comment: That sounds like the solution. Thank you very much for the suggestion!